# Capturing the beginning of a WIFI conversation

Tags: wifi, wireshark, packet-sniffers

I'm new to routers and networking so sorry for the maybe obvious question.

When I access my home router through WIFI from my laptop, the WIFI password is being sent from my computer through the WIFI card to router, followd by a response from the router.

Is it possible to use Wireshark or some other application in order to capture these packets (the packets that contains the actual encrypted password and the router response whether it is the correct password or not)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that using Wireshark.
Note that the password is sent by an IEEE802.11 management packet and you need to turn on [monitor mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_mode) to sniffer it.

Please refer to:

https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN#Turning_on_monitor_mode
https://www.acrylicwifi.com/en/blog/how-to-capture-wifi-traffic-using-wireshark-on-windows/ 
https://www.riverbed.com/products/steelcentral/steelcentral-riverbed-airpcap.html